# How to make large MongoDB request faster

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building an express API that queries a ton of data in a MongoDB via Mongoose. The DB is stored on MongoDB's Atlas. When my queries results in more than 10.000 documents, the queries starts to feel fairly slow. As in 15-20 seconds. At some point the data will grow to > 100.000 documents, and imagine performance will start to become an issue. My query seems fairly simple to me:

```
if (req.query.start_date && req.query.end_date) {
    query.date = {
        $gte: req.query.start_date,
        $lte: req.query.end_date,
    }
}

const line_items = await MyCollection.find(query);
res.json({line_items: line_items});
```

Note: I _id field in my collection that I assume is indexed?

Note that data is added every 10 minutes, so caching does not seem like a viable option.

What can I do to speed up me queries? And how much data is considered too much in a single query?

Comment: create index on date field with desc ordering... Also if you need to fetch all records use pagination... not always DB will be bottleneck... if fetching large dataset at once then network latency will also be there

Comment: Index `date`. It's the only thing your query is looking at and the only index that would be used. Besides that, way too broad. You don't specify what sort of date range you are looking at, how that relates to your collections, how many documents in the collection and in a typical result, or basically why you need many results *IF* this actually returns 100's or 1000's or insert large number here.

Comment: @NeilLunn: The date range can be anything from a single day, to 3 years. I do specify that the queries will result in more than 10.000 documents. Typically it will be around 10.000 documents per week in the specified date-range. Thank you so much for the reply :) I'll def try and index the date field. Can I expect big performance improvements from that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose ORM then you can use the **lean()** method for handling the huge data from the mongodb.

As described by the mongoose docs, documents returned from queries with the lean option true are plain javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied. So in this way the over head attached to the mongoose document is not there in case of lean and we get high performance.

```
MyCollection.find({'dob': {'$lte': +new Date()}},
        {},
        {limit:100, skip:0}
    ).lean().exec(function (err, data){
     console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting - will def. look into this as well.